# Learning Python: is there a better way to create dictionaries from a string list than this?

Tags: python

I am going through the Code Academy lessons on python and one lesson wants you to do the following.

Make three dictionaries named "lloyd", "alice", and "tyler. Then for each dictionary set the key name equal to "Lloyd", "Alice", and "Tyler" respectively. Then each dictionary should have three keys (homework, quizzes, and tests) equal to an empty list.

I came up with this:

```
students = ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]

for x in students:

    # capitalize first letter in name
    capital_name = x[0].upper() + x[1:]

    # make empty dictionary with student's name
    exec("%s = {}" % x)

    # define keys. For name, set equal to name with capitalized first letter
    exec("%s['name'] = capital_name" % x)
    exec("%s['homework'] = []" % x)
    exec("%s['quizzes'] = []" % x)
    exec("%s['tests'] = []" % x)

    eval("print(%s)" % x)
```

I added the print at the end to confirm what I did. I have learned to program like this in loops from using Stata which essentially evaluates what you are looping over literally (it does what exec / eval does without any additional commands).

If there were 1000 students it wouldn't be sensible to manually define the dictionary for each, so how would you do it other than how I just showed?

Comment: You wouldn't make separate variables for each dictionary.  Instead you would make a dictionary that has the student names as keys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @aruisdante yes, but maybe a dupe. Search first.

Comment: To expand on @BrenBarn's point, I suspect the lesson you're following expects you to hard-code the three dictionaries and repeat the code to do the assignments in each of them. Presumably later it will explain about loops and better ways of storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of doing it by setting a main dictionary holding each students information as a dictionary on its own.

```
students = ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]
students_dicts = {}

for s in students:
  students_dicts[s.capitalize()] = {'homework': [], 'quizzes': [], 'tests': []}

# if the single dicts is demanded, loop for them
for st in students_dicts:
  print("%s => " % st, students_dicts[st])
```

Unless the lessons is about Metaprogramming, then this should suffice.